# A word for "false self confidence"

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose a motorbike driver jumped above 2 cars in a show, and a crowd of girls gave him an applause. He then tried jumping over 100 cars, and lost his life halfway by falling into the row of cars.

What do you say to this state of feeling, this false self confidence that he wasn't aware of its falsehood?

Comment: **Excitement.** He got excited and killed himself:)

Comment: Good one, Thanks. Any other ... ?

Comment: Overconfidence?

Comment: This is ok but might someone have overconfidence without being praised by others. Is there any other word that carry the sudden feeling (like excitement) also the falsity and negative meaning ?

Comment: It's motorbike **rider**, if you want to edit your question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA what if we're both riding the same bike but you're driving?

Comment: Maybe it wasn't false self-confidence. It's more like stupidity. You can feel self-confident and still do something stupid....

Comment: [***Hubris***](https://www.institutelm.com/resourceLibrary/beware-of-executive-hubris.html), *defined as **excessive self-confidence** or pride...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Complacency** is the correct word to describe the act of the motorcyclist. Chambers defines *complacent* as:

- Showing satisfaction, esp when self-satisfied, usu with insufficient regard to problems, dangers, etc

The following sentence can describe the motorist aptly.

- The complacent motorist lost his life in a freak show of bravado.

Comment: A note about connotation. Complacency tends to be associated with lack of action, relying on past accomplishments, and maintenance of the status quo. [Hubris](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/123854/12150) tends to be associated with the opposite, though both come from a false or counterproductive sense of confidence.

Answer (score 14):

That sounds like the definition for the word [hubris](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hubris):

> exaggerated pride or self-confidence

Comment: +1, but a little more detail should be provided, including a reference to a source: (in Greek tragedy) an excess of ambition, pride, etc, ultimately causing the transgressor's ruin (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hubris)

Answer (score 4):

The whole situation—adulation and resulting recklessness—is probably most commonly summed up by "This [went to his head](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/go)." (Under what they label *phrasal verbs*, see "go to (one's) head," sense 2.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking he was "pumped" as in pumped up with confidence. Or he became reckless. His "ego  was inflated by the adulation" - or was "egotistical." He became overconfident. Also, bold, or cocky, or cocksure would fit the situation.

Comment: Couldn't  help but to laugh at ego **testical**

Answer (score 2):

I would probably describe such a person as **foolhardy**.

**Cocky** or **cockiness** both fit pretty well.  **Bravado** is close, too.  (The already mentioned *hubris* is perfect, but might seem too grand a concept in some contexts.)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the word for exaggerated self-confidence is **arrogance**. It may not be the best choice for your specific example though, since, at least to me, arrogance is a permanent quality -- one is either **arrogant** or not, you don't get arrogant when a crowd of girls applauds you.

Answer (score 0):

**Bravado** fits the situation perfectly I think.

a bold manner or **a show of boldness intended to impress** or intimidate:

http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bravado?q=bravado

Answer (score 0):

Jumpin four cars after successfully jumping two demonstrates self-confidence, but trying to jump *one hundred* goes *far beyond* that and could be called a

> **delusion**
>
> Anything that **deceives the mind** with a false impression; a deception;
> a fixed false opinion or belief with regard to objective things, esp.
> as a form of mental derangement OED

---

> When he first described this stunt to me, the tale sounded insane,
> **delusional**—but to my astonishment turns out to have been real. [Andrew Smith; *Totally Wired*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Totally_Wired/XhOLDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=stunt%20%20delusional&pg=PT296&printsec=frontcover)

> “The goal is to get from Point A to Point B as creatively as possible.
> So technically they are doing Parkour as long as Point A is
> **delusion** and Point B is the hospital.” [C. Van Dusen; "From delusion to the hospital"](https://www.atlantamagazine.com/health/from-delusion-to-the-hospital/)

> **Delusion** or *false unshakeable belief* is another kind of morbid thought process in schizophrenia. [A. K. Deb; *An Outline of
> Psychiatry*](https://www.google.com/search?q=stunt%20%20jump%20delusion&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AOaemvLW1HFfhShufYnRk2ils4P_3xR4QA:1631364443865&ei=W6U8YbykNOWl1QG5qJSIAw&start=30&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwj8vbOR-vbyAhXlUjUKHTkUBTE4FBDw0wN6BAgBEFM&biw=1117&bih=591&dpr=1.25)